# Поможет ли мне Apache Spark?

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark

У меня есть база данных MySQL с большими таблицами (~4-20G) и сервер Tableau для аналитиков. Запросы с Tableau работают слишком медленно. Я хочу между ними поставить Spark SQL, чтобы из  MySQL  делать только SELECT, а вся обработка будет в Spark.

Есть ли в этом смысл? И если есть, хватит ли одного кластера Spark?

Comment: Все зависит от данных, какого вида аналитика на них производится и где собственно затык. По идее tableau имеет механизм общения со Spark, поэтому скорее всего выигрыш будет. К тому же все зависит от кластера. Кластер - это набор серверов, который объединен между собой. Поэтому это может быть как три хлипких машины, там и десяток навороченных серверов нового поколения. Поэтому "один кластер" звучит размыто.

Comment: Я бы возможно попробовал провести настройку с помощью одного-двух компьютера со Spark, потом при отработанной настройке замерить производительность уже на [серверах Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/emr/features/spark/) и посмотреть, как это вообще будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо, буду тестировать. Сорри не правильно не много сформулировал вопрос, я только начал это изучать. "Один кластер" я имел ввиду спарк будет на одном сервере в одном экземпляре(только master без slave), пока не знаю сколько озу и cpu ядер  мне выделят.

Comment: Для Spark является критичным наличие ОЗУ, поскольку все вычисления он старается производить как раз в памяти. Ну и главная особенность как раз в том, чтобы экземпляров было много. Наличие одного сервера уже сомнительно, поэтому лучше протестируйте т.к. результат может быть наоборот хуже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO Spark Cluster, состоящий из единственного узла, не дает никаких преимуществ кроме Spark API и сопутствующих библиотек: `Spark SQL`, `Spark ML`, etc.

Вся "прелесть" обработки данных в `Spark Cluster` в возможности *параллельной* и *распределенной* обработки огромных массивов данных, которые не помещаются в память одного сервера. Разумеется существуют накладные расходы при работе со Spark. Я когда-то сравнивал скорость несложной обработки данных на одном узле Spark Cluster, используя `Spark SQL` и `Pandas` - на одном и том же железе. `Pandas` оказался почти в 10 раз быстрее. Поэтому я рассматривал использование Spark только если у вас есть реальная необходимость параллельной и распределенной обработки данных и если у вас есть соответствующее железо - с 3+ узлами кластера.

PS большинство функций из `Spark SQL` уже реализованы в `MySQL`, поэтому вы можете попробовать сделать все на стороне `MySQL` обычными запросами - это может сэкономить часть времени чтения и передачи данных.